# New Line in TextField

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to have some pre-defined text in my TextField, but I don't know how to add new lines in between the words. I tried \n, but it isn't working.

Code:

```
    package view;

import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Overview extends VBox{

    private TextField info;

    public Overview() {

        //Adds a little border around the app so the text field doesn't go to the edges
        this.setPadding(new Insets(30, 30, 30, 30));

        //----- Initialising text field --------
        info = new TextField("Name:\n" + "PNumber:\n"+ "Email:\n"+ "Date:\n"+ "Course:\n"+ ""+ "Selected Modules:\n"+ "==============");
        info.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        info.setMinHeight(850);
        info.setEditable(false);


        //------ Adding the text to the Text Field --------


        //-------- Putting it into VBox so that it stretches with the screen ----------
        VBox fit = new VBox(info);




        this.getChildren().add(fit);

    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to add a newline between each word?
I want there to be a separation between words and then it will automatically fill in the information later.

Comment: use `TextArea` instead of `TextField`

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh That fixed it, thank you :D

Comment: glad , pls accept the answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TextField` is only for single lines, it will not render multiple lines as you want your code to achieve. so instead of using `TextField` use `TextArea`.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the textarea instead of textfield. You can use the mulitple lines in textarea but textfield is a single line control